# Light intensity (affected by semiconductor's absorption)

Tags: semiconductor-physics

An experiment recently was done in order to measure the band gap of certain semiconductor.

In order to gather the transmission coefficient for a spectrum of light, a light intensity of the system (`light rays go to detector`) and a light intensity of the system with a sample semiconductor behind the detector (`light rays go through the semiconductor sample and reach detector`) were measured.

These are the resulting graphs:
[Intensities: System(red) | Sample(black)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkeoo.png)
[image]

Questions:

• Why does the red graph has a bump @ around 500nm? What is going on with slopes?

• Sample's voltage intercepts sytem's voltage which means that, if I plotted Transmission coefficient (`T= Intensity with sample / Intensity system`), I would get transmission in the range above about 630nm more that 100%. That is nonesence. Right?

• Are these results explainable?

I am using Lock-in AMP with chopper spinning @ 65.4Hz

[Set-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POlah.png)
[image]

Comment: Sorry, @The Photon. I was rushing this one + I am stupid. Yes, I was measuring intensity of light(red) and intensity of light which passed through semiconductor(black). I did this so that I could calculate transmission coeff. as mentioned above. I am going to edit my question.

Comment: Your edits are very helpful. I removed my comment as it no longer applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the red graph has a bump @ around 500nm?

Since it happens in the graph with the sample absent, it is a characteristic of something in your source. My guess is it is a feature of the long-pass filter.

> What is going on with slopes?

The red curve has an up-slope at the cut-off wavelength of the long-pass filter.

The blue curve has an up-slope at the wavelength where the sample under test starts to transmit light. This is related to the band-gap of the material.

> I would get transmission in the range above about 630nm more that 100%. That is nonesense. Right?

Your sample is going into the beam where it is converging on the detector. The sample has an index of refraction higher than 1 (probably quite a bit higher in the 2-3 range). Therefore the sample is changing the *optical distance* between the converging lens and the detector. In this case it looks like increasing the optical distance improves the coupling efficiency of the beam on the detector, leading to the appearance of a transmission coefficient above 1.0.

If you place the sample between the chopper and the converging lens, this effect should go away (assuming the sample is big enough to filter the entire beam in that location).

Comment: Thank you, @The Photon. What you say does make sense, and I mean you are the light itself answering.

Comment: However, I still do have last question: will I be able to extract reasonable values for absorption coefficients so that I could calculate the band gap energy? (BTW, My sample's refractive index @ range around 550nm is about 3.45, just to confirm your thoughts about transmission going over 1.0)